# How to convert MIPS pseudo-instructions

Tags: mips

So I am wanting to convert these pseudo instructions so my MIPS simulator can assemble without using pseudo-instructions. I am stuck trying to convert these. I know I can change li to addi/u also. I am needing to convert all pseudo instructions( li, la, move, etc.) Is there a key out there for this?

```
.data

name: .asciiz "Your name\n\n"

newline: .asciiz "\n"

prompt1: .asciiz "Enter the number of time to test: "

prompt2: .asciiz "\nThe smallest number is: "

prompt3: .asciiz "The largest number is: "

prompt4: .asciiz "\nError: there are no number to test\n"

prompt5: .asciiz "Enter number: "

.text

addi $t1, $s0, 1 #counter
li $t2,0

#$t4 #min
#$t5 #max

la $a0,name #print name
li $v0,4
syscall

la $a0,prompt1 #print Enter the number of times to test:
li $v0,4
syscall

li $v0,5 #input the integer t0 = test run
syscall
la $t0,($v0)

la $a0,newline #prints newline
li $v0,4
syscall

loop1:
bgt $t1,$t0,exit

la $a0,prompt5 #prints Enter numberof:
li $v0,4
syscall

li $v0,5 #inputs the integer
syscall

la $t3,($v0)
addi $t2,$t2,1 #nested counter

beqz $t3,loop2
beq $t2,1,set
bgt $t4,$t3,smaller
blt $t5,$t3,larger

j loop1

set:
move $t4,$t3
move $t5,$t3
j loop1

smaller:
move $t4,$t3
j loop1

exit:
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, read the [ask] page and update your question.

Comment: It's very simple: load up your program in the simulator with pseudo-instructions enabled and see what it converts the pseudo-instructions to. Then do the same conversion in your source code.

Comment: Thank you Michael, that helped me out tremendously.